# Dashlane not autocompleting fields in a dialog

Tags: html, password-manager

Basically I'm expecting Dashlane to autocomplete those fields.

This is a minimal example to reproduce the issue

https://jsbin.com/xidilavodo/edit?html,output

```
<dialog open>
  <form>
    Email
    <input type="email" autocomplete="email" />
    Password
    <input type="password" autocomplete="curent-password" />
  </form>
</dialog>
```